# New Google Cloud Module not present in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to create new google cloud module via android studio it is not visible in new module panel as given in the step 1 of the instruction in the following link :-https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints.

I have tried all the solutions given online but they don't seem to work.
Please help

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Module was previously available through Cloud Tools for Android Studio plugin.

Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't have Google Cloud Module for Android Studio version 3.0. Please see this link:

https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/

> Note: Creating App Engine-based cloud backends is not supported in
>   Android Studio 3.0; however, your existing projects with cloud
>   backends will continue to work in Android Studio.

We have to wait and see if the Android Studio team has plans on their roadmap to fix this.

Comment: So, in theory, if I import my project in Android Studio 2.x, add the cloud module there, then open it up in 3.0 again it should be imported and ready to use?

Comment: I just tested it and indeed, it works. 

1. Install and open Android Studio 2.3.3, open your project and ignore all the gradle warnings
2. Add Google Cloud Module like described in the official documentation (File -> New -> New Module...)
3. After adding the new module, close Android Studi 2.3.3 and open your project in Android Studio 3.0
4. Your project now has as Google App Engine Module

Comment: Do we have any update if app engine modules will be supported again ?  e.g. on 3.2+ version of android studio  ?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.1.3 and I still don't see support for this :(.

Comment: Hi folks, Android Studio 3.3.2 and still not having support for GCM :[